# ASP.NET: Exception when accessing the request InputStream

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application I'm trying to access the `Request.InputStream` property but I get the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RequestParser.MergeArrays(Byte[] array1, Byte[] array2)
at Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RequestParser.get_FirstBoundary()
at Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RequestParser..ctor(Byte[] boundary, Encoding encoding, RequestStateStore requestStateStore)
at Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.ProgressWorkerRequest.get_Parser()
at Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.ProgressWorkerRequest.UpdateProgress(Byte[] buffer, Int32 validBytes
at Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.ProgressWorkerRequest.GetPreloadedEntityBody()
at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()
```

As you can see, the exception is thrown by a Telerik component. I'm indeed using Telerik web controls in my project but none of them are related to this controller. The exception occurs even if I generate a request using a tool. Looks to me like Telerik somehow injected this ProgressWorkerRequest object into my HttpRequest.

Any clues on how to get rid of it?

Comment: You should have included your controller code you are using to upload a file or whatever it is you are doing that has a way to access `Request.InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be related to your controller.  It is related to the process that the Telerik uploader is conducting and is not something to "get rid of".  Basically, it is telling you that the Telerik uploader process didn't complete because it didn't find what it was expecting to.

Since Telerik controls are generally straightforward to use, you should only need something like this to get the input stream for your file:

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUploader)
{
    if (Request.Files.Count == 1)
    {
        string fileName = Request.Files[0].FileName;
        Stream s = Request.Files[0].InputStream;
        int size = Request.Files[0].ContentLength; 
        byte[] myFile = new byte[length];
        s.Read(myFile, 0, size);
        // Now, myFile should have the file, in bytes
    }
}
```

If you are not getting the file, I would ensure the application has the permissions via the account it is acting under (either yours, or a service account, if a web application) to the resource you are pointing at.